# Show category with link

Tags: categories

I am trying to show the category of posts with link to its page, so I used this code but I don't know What's wrong with it. It is only showing the category without link.

```
<p class="subjectCat"><?php
   foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
     echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
      echo $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );                          
   } 
?></a></p>
```

Comment: Are you trying to show a link to a certain post's category or list all possible categories and link? If you want a complete list than Pieter's answer should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

You should look at [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category). You are probably looking for something like this as from the codex

```
   <?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>
```